# Current menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

I've been trying every single tutorial I found online and none seems to work for me.

I've got these buttons:

```
    <a href='faq.php'><div class='button'>
    <div class='button_top'>
    </div>
    <div class='button_bot'>
    FAQ
    </div></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6G8bk/

and I'd like that the top of the button would stay highlighted if the page url is same as href of the button.

Ty for any answers in advance!

Here's the fixed jsfiddle with jquery I tried but still won't work: http://jsfiddle.net/6G8bk/4/

Comment: did you mean if href is equal to current url?

Comment: The most common way I've seen to accomplish this is to give the active tab an "active" or similar class name and handle it in the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/6G8bk/1/.

Comment: @Utkanos I fixed html

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti Yes

Comment: @Coh3n I've got a menu.html file that loads into all pages. If I did so I'd have to copy menu to each page and in case I'd change it I'd have to change every file.

Comment: Ah yes, I've done the same thing in the past. In that case you can use JavaScript to add/remove the active class. Also, your jQuery function doesn't work in JSFiddle because the page's URL isn't the same as what it would be on your website, and your jQuery selector isn't quite right. You have it look for the a tag inside an element with .button class, which you don't have in your HTML.

Comment: @Coh3n I have button class in html. The problem is CSS has to change button_top. Can't manage to get that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. In your jQuery, you're trying to select all `<a>` elements that have a parent class of `button`, and according to your HTML you do not have (the `button` class is a child of the `<a>` element).
2. The page's URL won't work in JSFiddle because it will get the JSFiddle link, which will be different from the one on your website.
3. Since you want `button_top` to be visible on hover, you'll need to use JavaScript. As fas as I know, you can't manipulate another element on hover with pure CSS.

Here is a working Fiddle of what I think you want. I've left comments in the code that might help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/6G8bk/6/

Comment: Ty! Managed to make it work with the first part of your code. As for second I think it's just hover option? I got hover covered in CSS. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh and BTW maybe know if there's something I can add so Home button will work without link.com/index.php? So just link.com

Comment: I believe if you have a index.php file you can just reference the link like link.com/. If the index.php still shows in the address bar, you may need to link a HTML file inside your index.php file, like here: [here](https://github.com/Coh3n/Website/blob/master/index.php). If you look at [my personal website](http://cohenadair.com/) you'll see that none of the index pages show in the address bar.

Comment: I linked everything from "/" to "index.php". I'll try to make a fix when I'm done with rest. Ty very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current url page by using $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] and comparing it to each element of the menu.

If it match, you put another class in the menu element with CSS rules to have the layout you want.

Comment: I was using this:
    $(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $(".button a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});    

But if this works then I can't change css with anything I try.

Like: .button_top .active
Tried everything.

New here dunno how to make the code work in comments sorry.